# Can we interchange @Controller and @Service in spring?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-annotations

Can we interchange @Controller and @Service in spring? I tried and it was working. How are they implemented internally?

Answer (score 2):

@Controller and @Service are special form of @Component. Spring allows you to use it interchangeably, but is it NOT recommended to do it that way. As for instance the @Controller is used on classes to that serves are the Controller on the MVC. Also, spring dispatcher servlet will scan for @RequestMapping on classes which are annotated using @Controller.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Component
    ------@Controller
    ------@Service
    ------@Repository
```

`@Controller` and `@Service` are ultimately part of `@Component`. You may interchange them but it is not recommended or follow best practices. The purpose of using 3 different annotation is to we can have separate the layers based on it use more appropriate annotation.

**@Controller:**

- Annotated class indicates that it is a controller component, and mainly used at the presentation layer.
- @Controller is used to mark classes as Spring MVC Controller. This annotation is just a specialized version of @Component and it allows the controller classes to be auto-detected based on classpath scanning.

**@Service:** 
It indicates annotated class is a Service component in the business layer.